# How do I create a `ITypeElement` with represents a closed generic type in a ReSharper plugin?

Tags: c#, generics, resharper-8.0, resharper-plugins

I'm using the ReSharper 8 sdk and want to find all inheritors of a particular generic interface, where the generic type is a particular type. I have [asked a more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30918419/97614) which got most of the way there, but I am only able to find any implementation of `ICommandHandler<T>` and not the one implementation I want, `ICommandHandler<TestCommand>`

this is the code I have:

```
foreach (var psiModule in declaredElement.GetPsiServices().Modules.GetModules())
{
    IDeclaredType genericType = TypeFactory.CreateTypeByCLRName("HandlerNavigationTest.ICommandHandler`1", psiModule, theClass.ResolveContext);
    var genericTypeElement = genericType.GetTypeElement();
    if (genericTypeElement != null)
    {                    
        var theType = TypeFactory.CreateType(originalTypeElement);
        var commandHandlerType = TypeFactory.CreateType(genericTypeElement,theType);
        var handlerTypeelement = commandHandlerType.GetTypeElement();
        solution.GetPsiServices().Finder.FindInheritors(handlerTypeelement, searchDomainFactory.CreateSearchDomain(solution, true),
        inheritorsConsumer, NullProgressIndicator.Instance);
        var inheritedInstance= inheritorsConsumer.FoundElements.First();
        var sourceFile = inheritedInstance.GetSourceFiles().First();
    }
}
```

if I tooltip the commandHandlerType after this line:

var commandHandlerType = TypeFactory.CreateType(genericTypeElement,theType);

I see that the type is correctly specified:

[image: Generic type exists!]

But then when I get the `ITypeElement` from this type to pass into my search using this line

```
var handlerTypeelement = commandHandlerType.GetTypeElement();
```

I seem to have lost the type:

[image: Generic type lost!]

And so my search finds all implementations of the `ICommandHandler<T>`.

So my question is, how do I create the `ITypeElement` which represents the closed generic type I want to search for?

Or alternatively: How can I search the returned collection of inheritors for the type which has the class I started with as the generic type parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, that makes sense. An `ITypeElement` is an instance of `IDeclaredElement`, which means it's something that has a declaration - such as a class or interface declaration. So when you get an `IType` that represents your closed generic, it's made up of an `ITypeElement` that represents the generic type (`ICommandHandler`) and an `ISubstitution` that represents the resolved generic type parameters (`AnotherCommand`). When you call `IType.GetTypeElement()`, it will return the type element part of the type element/substitution pair, which is the open generic declared element (because an interface declaration can only ever be open).

I think you might have to take the alternative approach, and find all inheritors (implementors) of `ITypeHandler<T>` and filter them down in the consumer. The `FindResult` passed to the consumer can be downcast to a `FindResultInheritedElement`, which will give you a declared element that represents the class that implements `ITypeHandler<T>`. You should be able to walk these elements' interfaces to see what they implement, and only accept those find results that implement the correct `T`. I think `TypeElementUtil` will help here to get all super types (base types + interfaces) of the declared element.

Comment: As I had already created the generic type earlier I could just use the `GetAllSuperTypes()` method and then check each returned type to see if it was the generic type I was interested in and if it was then I could navigate to it. So now I have to bones of it working.  Just need to make the command/handler types readable from the config and then it should be flexible enough to generally useful.

Comment: ok, so [another blocker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168095/how-do-i-get-a-window-context-so-i-can-create-navigationoptions-in-a-resharper-p), if you could nudge me in the right direction please...