# How do I get a window context so I can create NavigationOptions in a resharper plugin

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-plugins, resharper-8.2

I have a [navigation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918419/create-a-generic-type-to-find-implementations-of-in-a-resharper-plugin) which I want to extend to allow support for context navigation. I've got everything I need except for the NavigationOptions instance. In my `INavigateFromHereProvider` I get  called with an `IDataContext` so can create the `NavigationOptions` from this using the `NavigationOptions.FromDataContext` method. Great.

In my context action I don't get called with a `IDataContext`, I get given a `ICSharpContextActionDataProvider` during construction. I can get my `IDeclaredElement` from this to base my navigation decision on, but I'm not sure how to create my `NavigationOptions` instance. It feels like I should be using `NavigationOptions.FromWindowContext` but I seems to need a `PopupWindowContextSource` and I don't know where to get one of these from.

So where can I get a relevant `PopupWindowContextSource` to create my `NavigationOptions` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, discovered the answer (well, an answer).

I can use this:

```
 var popupWindowContextSource = solution.GetComponent<MainWindowPopupWindowContext>().Source;
```

I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate thing to use, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using `NavigationOptions.FromDataContext`. This will pull a window context from the `IDataContext` that you've already got. This should give you a popup window context that's appropriate to where you've been invoked from - anchored to the editor window, or the tree view, or whatever. Using the `MainWindowPopupContext` will give you a context that's based on the main Visual Studio window, which will likely work and be fine, but might not be the most relevant.

Comment: I don't have a `IDataContext` at this point. I'm adding support for doing the navigation via Alt-Enter (a context action) so in my `IsAvailable(IUserDataHolder cache)` method I only have access to the `ICSharpContextActionDataProvider ` I was given in the constructor

Comment: It's in this method that I want to get a popupwindowcontextsource

Comment: Oops. Misread the question. I think using `MainWindowPopupContext` is fine, then, or you could even create your own that derives from `PopupWindowContext`.