# How to find a type by FQN in a solution?

Tags: c#, resharper, rider, resharper-plugins

I am writing a Rider/ReSharper nav-from-here plugin which is supposed to determine a target type based on a symbol I am standing on using some simple rules, and finally, navigate to it.

The first part is okay, I have managed to form the FQN needed, but I am struggling with the navigation. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30978242/4012887) StackOverflow post, and thought I might try this approach. So I have been trying to use `TypeFactory.CreateTypeByCLRName` for like two hours to create an `IDeclaredType` instance to be able to get the `IDeclaredElement` using `GetTypeElement()` and eventually get its declarations. But the API seems to have changed and no matter what I do I cannot get my code to work.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
// does not work with Modules.GetModules(), either
foreach (var psiModule in solution.GetPsiServices().Modules.GetSourceModules())
{
    var type = TypeFactory.CreateTypeByCLRName("MyNamespace.MyClassName", psiModule);
    var typeElement = type.GetTypeElement();

    if (typeElement != null)
    {
        MessageBox.ShowInfo(psiModule.Name); // to make sure sth is happening
        break;
    }
}
```

The weird part is, I actually see a message box - but only when the tab with `MyClassName.cs` is active. When it is in focus, everything is fine. When it's not or the file is closed, the class does not get resolved, `type.IsResolved` is `false`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you should have a `IPsiModule` instance from the context where you plan to use the type you're looking for. You can get it from some syntax node you're working with via `.GetPsiModule()` method or via many other ways (like `dataContext.GetData(PsiDataConstants.SOURCE_FILE)?.GetPsiModule()`.

```cs
void FindTypes(string fullTypeName, IPsiModule psiModule)
{
  // access the symbol cache where all the solution types are stored
  var symbolCache = psiModule.GetPsiServices().Symbols;

  // get a view on that cache from specific IPsiModule, include all referenced assemblies
  var symbolScope = symbolCache.GetSymbolScope(psiModule, withReferences: true, caseSensitive: true);

  // or use this to search through all of the solution types
  // var symbolScope = symbolCache.GetSymbolScope(LibrarySymbolScope.FULL, caseSensitive: true);

  // request all the type symbols with the specified full type name
  foreach (var typeElement in symbolScope.GetTypeElementsByCLRName(fullTypeName))
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But holy cow, I wasn't even close to the solution! :) Want to point out that I don't have a direct reference to the target project, so only the second approach with `LibrarySymbolScope.FULL` works for me.